# Issue with SqlCommand Parameters

Tags: c#, sql

When I execute the following query in SSMS I get the expected result i.e. '1'

```
SELECT TSID
FROM tblTimesheets
WHERE TSUser = 'PJW' AND TSDate = '2012-01-18';
```

However, when the SqlCommand is produced by the code in my application the ExecuteScalar fails (it simply causes the method to exit with no error message).

```
public int GetID(string paramUser, DateTime paramDate)
    {
        string strSql = "SELECT TSID " +
                        "FROM tblTimesheets " +
                        "WHERE TSUser = @TSUser AND TSDate = @TSDate;";

        string strConnection = BuildConnectionString();
        SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        linkToDB.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(strSql, linkToDB);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@TSUser", SqlDbType.Text);
        sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@TSDate", SqlDbType.Date);
        sqlCom.Parameters["@TSUser"].Value = paramUser;
        sqlCom.Parameters["@TSDate"].Value = paramDate;


        int intResult = (Int32)sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
        linkToDB.Close();
        return intResult;
    }
```

I've stepped through the code and can confirm the parameters are PJW and 2012-01-18 as required, but the ExecuteScalar returns any data, which I know should be there based on my comparable query in SSMS.

Please assist.

Comment: Can you run SQL Profiler, and find that statement hitting the DB? Grab the statement, and try running that manually in SSMS - should be easier to spot if you have the exact SQL hitting the db.

Comment: What does SQL Profiler show being executed on the server?

Comment: I know this is trivial, but are you sure the connection string is pointing to the same database? Do you connect using the same database user (maybe you are connecting through SSMS using your domain account, while your code is using a named account with less privileges)?

Comment: also, is `paramDate` *exactly* a date (i.e. midnight or similar)? could it be due to time-part, perhaps?

Comment: OK I've answered my own question after some considerable head scratching - but apparently I'm not allowed to pot an answer to my own questions yet - so I'll have to do it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for all your ideas.  In the end it turned out to be the user Parameter.

paramUser is declared as a String.

However I thought it was OK to call the method, by passing in one of the string properties belonging to my class cUser, as follows:

int myInt = GetID(cUser.UserID, Date)

However when I changed this to

string strUser = cUser.UserID;
int myInt = GetID(strUser, Date)

it worked!

I'm not entirely clear why though.  I'd be grateful if someone could explain why the extra line should make a difference.

Comment: and the text formatting in these comments is rubbish so thats probably clear as mud, now all the indenting and spacing has vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SqlDbType.Text` try any of the following, depending on the type of the column:

- `SqlDbType.VarChar`
- `SqlDbType.NVarChar`
- `SqlDbType.NText`
- `SqlDbType.NChar`
- `SqlDbType.Char`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TSID
FROM tblTimesheets
WHERE TSUser = 'PJW' AND TSDate = '2012-01-18';
```

Here U r passing the exact date as parameter

Where as while passing the parameter in to the stored procedure you are passing 
"DateTime paramDate"

A date time variable

May be you need to parse to exact date format as supported by the stored procedure 
i.e you need to format the paramDate variable to 'YYYY-mm-DD'

I am not sure.. Try it.. and reply if it helps or not !

Comment: The SqlDbType of the parameter is Date though, so even if paramDate has a time, that should be stripped off before hitting the DB.

Answer (score 1):

When the parameter is of DB type `date`, it is a good practice to defensively strip the time part on setting the parameter, like this:

```
sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@TSDate", SqlDbType.Date);
sqlCom.Parameters["@TSDate"].Value = paramDate.Date;
```

Please let me know if this does not help, and I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say the `ExecuteScalar` fails with no error message. Wrap your code in a try-catch block to make sure any exceptions that `ExecuteScalar()` might be throwing are caught.

Other than that try and do as others have suggested and view the SQL produced using SQL Profiler, then run that SQL in SSMS to compare results.